# ggplot fill does not work - no errors [MRE]

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill

the ggplot analysis below is intended show number of survey responses by date. I'd like to **color the bars** by the three survey administrations (the Admini variable).While there are no errors thrown, the bars do not color.

Can anyone point out how/why my bars are not color-coded?  THANKS!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(RCurl)
OSTadminDates2<-getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bac3917/Cauldron/master/OSTadminDates.csv")
OSTadminDates<-read.csv(text=OSTadminDates2)

ndate1<-as.Date(OSTadminDates$Date,"%m/%d/%y");ndate1
SurvAdmin<-as.factor(OSTadminDates$Admini)

R<-ggplot(data=OSTadminDates,aes(x=ndate1),fill=Admini,group=1) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "count",width = .5 )

R
```

Comment: `fill = Admini` is outside of your `aes()` call, for starters.

Comment: Moved the fill=Admini inside aes()  but this did not help

Comment: Maybe you meant for `Admini` to be a factor?

Comment: (1) Your admini variable does NOT contain survey administrations, but simply the year (I think). (2) with stat = "count", you count the number of observations and display that at the Y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a work-around you could use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(RCurl)
OSTadminDates2<-getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bac3917/Cauldron/master/OSTadminDates.csv")
OSTadminDates<-read.csv(text=OSTadminDates2)

OSTadminDates$Date<-as.Date(OSTadminDates$Date,"%m/%d/%y")
OSTadminDates$Admini <- factor(OSTadminDates$Admini)

df <- OSTadminDates %>%
  group_by(Date, Admini) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Date, y = n, fill = Admini), stat = "identity")
```

[image]